# Passivation error caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.wsf.spi.serviceref.ServiceRefMetaData

Tags: java, jboss

We have a stateful session bean which is working perfectly. The stateful session bean has the following annotations:

```
@Stateful
@SerializedConcurrentAccess
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Name("XXXSession")
@Interceptors(SeamInterceptor.class)
```

The session bean gets passivated when the timeout exceeds (defined in ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml). But the passivation process fails and we are receiving the following stacktrace.
I would like to debug this in depth, but I don't know where to start. I guess we cannot see the actual exception, but how can I see what's going wrong?

So I'm not looking for an answer on the ClassNotFoundException. We did something wrong as developers, but I'm looking for a way to find out what exactly I did wrong. Because the exception is really making it hard to find out what's going wrong ... :-(

I'm using JBoss 6.1.0.Final (running on Mac OS X 10.7 and Java 1.6)

```
org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,080 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,080 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,080 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.defaultWrite(RegularObjectPersister.java:90)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeData(RegularObjectPersister.java:62)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.defaultWrite(RegularObjectPersister.java:90)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeData(RegularObjectPersister.java:62)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.defaultWrite(RegularObjectPersister.java:90)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeData(RegularObjectPersister.java:62)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.defaultWrite(RegularObjectPersister.java:90)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,081 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeData(RegularObjectPersister.java:62)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.defaultWrite(RegularObjectPersister.java:90)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeData(RegularObjectPersister.java:62)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.defaultWrite(RegularObjectPersister.java:90)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeData(RegularObjectPersister.java:62)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.defaultWrite(RegularObjectPersister.java:90)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeData(RegularObjectPersister.java:62)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.defaultWrite(RegularObjectPersister.java:90)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,082 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeData(RegularObjectPersister.java:62)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.defaultWrite(RegularObjectPersister.java:90)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeData(RegularObjectPersister.java:62)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.defaultWrite(RegularObjectPersister.java:90)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeData(RegularObjectPersister.java:62)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.ArrayPersister.saveObjectArray(ArrayPersister.java:110)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.ArrayPersister.writeData(ArrayPersister.java:101)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.io.JBossObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JBossObjectOutputStream.java:181)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.io.JBossObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JBossObjectOutputStream.java:181)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.io.MarshalledObject.(MarshalledObject.java:51)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,083 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulBeanContext.writeExternal(StatefulBeanContext.java:1048)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.ExternalizePersister.writeData(ExternalizePersister.java:58)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.io.JBossObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(JBossObjectOutputStream.java:181)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.StatefulSessionFilePersistenceManager.passivateSession(StatefulSessionFilePersistenceMan$
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.SimpleStatefulCache.passivate(SimpleStatefulCache.java:397)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.SimpleStatefulCache$SessionTimeoutTask.run(SimpleStatefulCache.java:301)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/wsf/spi/serviceref/ServiceRefMetaData
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1935)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.classmetamodel.ClassMetaData.lookupMethodOnHierarchy(ClassMetaData.java:102)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.classmetamodel.ClassMetaData.lookupInternalMethods(ClassMetaData.java:432)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.classmetamodel.ClassMetaData.(ClassMetaData.java:122)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.classmetamodel.ClassMetamodelFactory.getClassMetaData(ClassMetamodelFactory.java:350)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:168)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,084 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.ArrayPersister.saveObjectArray(ArrayPersister.java:110)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.ArrayPersister.writeData(ArrayPersister.java:101)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.describeObject(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:276)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectOutput.writeObject(DataContainer.java:206)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.writeSlotWithFields(RegularObjectPersister.java:182)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.ObjectOutputStreamProxy.writeFields(ObjectOutputStreamProxy.java:79)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.serial.persister.ObjectOutputStreamProxy.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStreamProxy.java:68)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at java.util.Vector.writeObject(Vector.java:1012)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       ... 256 more
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.wsf.spi.serviceref.ServiceRefMetaData from BaseClassLoader@12f483b4{vf$
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:480)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
2012-07-18 17:06:19,085 ERROR [STDERR] (SFSB Passivation Thread - jboss.j2ee:ear=XXX.ear,jar=XXX-YYY.jar,name=XXXSessionBean,service=EJB3)       ... 273 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the source code of JBoss Serialization and I've attached the code to my JBoss installation.
Problem seems to be related to a property ResourceBundle which is in my XXXSessionBean. Passivation fails on this property, because this object cannot be serialized (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). When I mark it as "transient", the problem seems to be resolved!

If you want to know how I got to this solution, please read the following blogpost: http://www.jochus.be/site/2012-08-06/java/debugging-passivation-errors-in-jboss